# Eclipse hovering over variables blackscreen

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I hover over a variable or try and see an object's methods, eclipse keeps giving me a black screen. I can highlight the text and see it that way but it's super inconvenient. I've tried going into preferences and resetting the "hover", restarted eclipse, closed and reopened the program, but it doesn't seem to fix anything.

[image]

Here's what it looks like. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That part is supposed to show the Javadoc. Does the separate javadoc view work? (Window -> Show View -> Javadoc)

Comment: What OS and desktop environment are you using? This "black tool tips" problem seems to be [quite common with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eclipse+tooltip+black), and different reasons and fixes seem to be possible.

Comment: Yea I was trying to search for it before posting, but couldn't quite figure out the name of the "javadoc". Going to the answer below helped solve the program. It was white so I just changed it to another colour and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change color in General>Appearance>Colors and Fonts>Basic>
*Information background color
*Information text color

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it works while i set it color and them to default. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me:
**Window>Preferences>Appearance**:
choose **Theme: Light**
**Color and Font theme: Default**

**Window>Preferences>Appearance>Color and Fonts** click "**Restore Defaults**", then "**Apply**" and finally "**Apply and Close**".

Restart Eclipse if necessary!